# Changing key format for signing commits

Tags: git, github, ssh, commit, gnupg

I'm trying to set a gpg key to sign comments for work.
Yesterday I tried to use the ssh key to do that and I changed the format to ssh with the commnand `git config [--global] gpg.format ssh`, but today I generated a gpg key and I would like to use that instead of the ssh but now I don't know how to change the format because if I use the same command and change ssh to gpg it gives me this error:

error: unsupported value for gpg.format: pgp
fatal: bad config variable 'gpg.format' in file 'C:/Users/....

Anyone knows how to reset this or change to gpg again? thanks all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Possible values](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gpgformat) are "openpgp", "x509", "ssh". You need "openpgp":

```
git config --global gpg.format openpgp
```

This is the default value so you can just remove the key at all:

```
git config --global --unset gpg.format
```